# UITextView issue with bottom anchor iOS

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I have created an input container for one chat app. Container is made from one: `UIView` which contains `UIImageView`, `UITextView` and `UIButton` all made programatically. But problem which I have is I can not move `UITextView` from bottom. It's little bit covers by keyboard. Putting `bottomAnchor` doesn't move `UITextView` but `topAnchor` works fine. Here is the image:

[image]

I tried many approaches but I can not make it work. Here is the code of `UITextView` and `constraints`:

```
lazy var inputTextField: UITextView = {
    let textField = UITextView()
    textField.text = "Enter message..."
    textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textField.font = UIFont(name: (textField.font?.fontName)!, size: 18)
    textField.layer.borderWidth = 1
    textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    textField.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    textField.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 15.0, left: 8.0, bottom: 0, right: 8.0)
    textField.delegate = self
    return textField
}()
```

And constraints:

```
        addSubview(self.inputTextField)
    //x,y,w,h
    self.inputTextField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uploadImageView.rightAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    self.inputTextField.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sendButton.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    self.inputTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor).isActive = true
    self.inputTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: separatorLineView.topAnchor, constant: 5.0).isActive = true

//bottom anchor doesn't work
    self.inputTextField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 5.0)
        .isActive = true
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try changing the constant of the bottom constraint from 5 to -5.

Comment: where u r adding ur textField as subview

Comment: @lorenzoliveto Tried that already doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: @AbhaySingh first line:  `addSubview(self.inputTextField)`

Comment: Could you post here or on GitHub how you're creating the entire view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this!

```
self.inputTextField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uploadImageView.rightAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
self.inputTextField.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sendButton.leftAnchor).isActive = true
self.inputTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: separatorLineView.topAnchor, constant: 5.0).isActive = true
self.inputTextField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 5.0).isActive = true
```

The problem is that you've already given the height so the bottom anchor is useless! I hope I've helped you!

Comment: Ah yes you are right. By removing `height` and changing  `constant: -5.0` it actually works. I'm Android developer and this was one of my first apps for iOS so I'm very beginner in this. Thanks for your help. Thumbs up.

Comment: Hey don't worry, I'm a beginner too so I understand your problems!

Answer (score 1):

From the Below Code, It Wont Work because height constraints have been given so either top and Height will work or Bottom and Height will Work.

```
    addSubview(self.inputTextField)
//x,y,w,h
self.inputTextField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uploadImageView.rightAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
self.inputTextField.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sendButton.leftAnchor).isActive = true
self.inputTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor).isActive = true
self.inputTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: separatorLineView.topAnchor, constant: 5.0).isActive = true

//bottom anchor doesn't work
    self.inputTextField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 5.0)
        .isActive = true
```

In Your Scenario, you should change the `separatorLineView` Constraints.(ie)Hide the `separatorLineView` `bottomConstraints`, Just Move the `separatorLineView` Little more top, this will automatically move your textfield to the desired position.

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: inputTextField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: separatorLineView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([topConstraint])
```